# cs50 speller "unload" memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

My cs50 speller function finally works, but when entering it into check50, it says there is a memory error with Valgrind. Here is my unload function which is supposed to free up all of the allocated memory from before.

```
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *pointer = table[i];

        while (table[i] != NULL && pointer != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = pointer;
            pointer = pointer->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        free(pointer);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Run valgrind yourself. See what the report tells you.

Comment: Too much guessing required. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The code seems to free the NULL pointer at the end of each linked list. I.e. the `free(pointer);` is unneeded. No idea how Valgrind reacts to that.

Comment: After `pointer = table[i];`, why `while (table[i] != NULL && pointer != NULL)` instead of simply `while (pointer != NULL)`? Dou expect `table[i]` to become NULL at some point?

Comment: Valgrind says that there is no error so I think its a problem with check50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little thinking through the loop, you can determine that by the time you get to the `free(pointer)` call, `pointer` is already NULL. You can't deallocate a NULL pointer.

I wouldn't have been surprised to learn that Valgrind could find that error, but nor am I surprised that it doesn't. It's not perfect. And there may or may not be a problem with check50 (it might just be using a different version of Valgrind than you are, if check50 is running on some other machine), but you still should remove the `free(pointer)` line.

And Yunnosch's comment is correct: you don't need to check if `table[i] != NULL`; it will always be NULL when `pointer` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool unload(void)

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    node *pointer = table[i];

    while (pointer)
    {
        node *tmp = pointer;
        pointer = pointer->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.